# Randomness in Sudoku solving algorithm

Tags: c#, random, backtracking, sudoku

I am using this backtracking soduku solving algorithm which is really good and efficient

```
    private void solve()
    {
        for (var y = 8; y >= 0; y--)
        {
            for (var x = 8; x >= 0; x--)
            {
                var a = grid[y, x];
                if (a == 0)
                {
                    for (var n = 1; n <= 9; n++)
                    {
                        if (possible(y, x, n))
                        {
                            grid[y, x] = n;
                            solve();
                            grid[y, x] = 0;
                        }
                    }
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
        print();
    }
```

The thing is i want to add a little change which I haven't been able to do and it is that instead of trying numbers 1 to 9 in order i want it to choose a random number from 1 to 9, and then set it in the grid, without repetition of course.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Any ideas on how to do it but not sure how to implement it?

Comment: Create an array or collection of the 9 numbers, use Fisher-Yates shuffle to shuffle the collection, then loop through it picking the numbers from it, thus in random order.

Comment: @Kevin Getting the random number is pretty easy with the Random.Next() function. What has given me the most trouble is not repeating then. For that I've tried a Hashset, and some other ideas i found on the internet like having a list of numbers 1 to 9 and removing them when they are used. Those didn't work,

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I´ll look it up, thanks

Comment: @INN_ Edit what you tried into the question and let's see what we can do with it

Comment: Check this fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/hu7x4U

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static class MyRandomGenerator
{
    private static Random random = new Random();

    public static int[] Generate(int inclusiveMinValue, int exclusiveMaxValue)
    {
        if (exclusiveMaxValue <= inclusiveMinValue)
            throw new ArgumentException(nameof(exclusiveMaxValue));

        var capacity = exclusiveMaxValue - inclusiveMinValue;
        var result = new HashSet<int>(capacity);

        while (result.Count < capacity)
        {
            result.Add(random.Next(inclusiveMinValue, exclusiveMaxValue));
        }

        return result.ToArray();
    }            
}
```

Comment: It is much better to implement this using a shuffling algorithm, such as Fisher-Yates shuffle. With sufficient large numbers for this method, it will have exponential runtime as the search for the last number will take relatively long time if there is sufficient large range of numbers to choose from.

Comment: Also, HashSet does in no way guarantee the order, and might even impact the randomness negatively. What I mean by this is that the order you add the numbers to the hash set in, might not be the order they end up in. If the hash set has to be resized, it may reorder the numbers, and the hash code generation used to pick buckets might not be random enough for this. Now, for a sudoku algorithm it is probably overkill either way, but I wouldn't use this as a general purpose "create list of random numbers" implementation.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Also, couldn't this function generate duplicate values of some numbers while omitting others?  Don't we want 1 of each number?

Comment: The method Maradik has picked will not generate duplicate numbers, that is why he's using a hashset. A hashset will refuse to add a value if it's already in there, that is why the loop is a while loop. He keeps *trying* to add a random value until he's added enough of them, but each value will only be added once. In this respect there is nothing wrong with the code in the answer. I just feel it has a very poor performance profile, but that is just my opinion.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen you are right, my solution has performance issues. But it's very simple and solve original task. You should not use my solution for production and high loaded systems.